# How I can run mocha tests in non parallel mode in a repeating loop?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I want to run a mocha tests in a loop repeatedly in a non-parallel mode. But looks like the tests are added to the mocha only for the first iteration. Ten the log shows 0 ran tests.

Here's the main file (it requires mocha installed):

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path');
const Mocha = require('mocha');

getFiles = dir => { // returns tests files as an array
    const files = []
    let resolvedPath = path.resolve(dir);
    
    for (const file of fs.readdirSync(dir)) {
        const fullPath = resolvedPath + '/' + file
        if (fs.lstatSync(fullPath).isDirectory())
            getFiles(fullPath).forEach(x => files.push(file + '/' + x))
        else if (file.endsWith('.js')) {
            files.push(fullPath)
        }
    }
    return files
}

function delay(time) { // used for sleep within the start function
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
} 

async function start(testsPath) {
    
    let testFiles = getFiles(testsPath);
    let failedTestsCount = -1;
    
   while(true) {
        console.log("starting a new iteration")
        let mocha = await new Mocha();
        for (let i = 0; i < testFiles.length; i++) {
            mocha.addFile(testFiles[i]);
        }
        
        mocha.parallelMode(false);

        await mocha.run(failed => {
            failedTestsCount = failed;
        });
        console.log("Failed tests: " + failedTestsCount)
        await delay(1000*60) // 1 minute   
    }      
}

start('./tests');
```

And there's one sub-directory called `tests` where the tests files are stored. In sake of simplicity it contains only one file (it requires chai installed):

```
let expect = require("chai").expect;

describe("Very Simple Tests", async function() {  

    it("passing", async function() {
        expect(true).to.equal(false);
    });

    it("failing", async function() {
        expect(true).to.equal(true);
    });  
});
```

And I'm getting the following output (only for the first iteration the tests are loaded):

```
  Very Simple Tests
    1) passing
    ✔ failing


  1 passing (3ms)
  1 failing

  1) Very Simple Tests
       passing:

      AssertionError: expected true to equal false
      + expected - actual

      -true
      +false
      
      at Context.<anonymous> (tests/tests.js:6:25)
      at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:476:21)



starting a new iteration
Failed tests: 1


  0 passing (0ms)
```

Strangely in parallel mode they are running ok, but in some cases I need a consecutive mode. I've tried some configurations but nothing seems to help.

Running them through a shell script and command line options for mocha is far from the best option for me ,as I need to make the results visible through an endpoint in express.

How I can make this running in non-parallel mode?

Comment: ahaa.. looks I need to use dispose() or unloadTests()  ..or both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add unloadFiles in the loop (or dispose):

```
   while(true) {
        console.log("starting a new iteration")
        let mocha = await new Mocha();
        for (let i = 0; i < testFiles.length; i++) {
            mocha.addFile(testFiles[i]);
        }
        
        mocha.parallelMode(false);

        await mocha.run(failed => {
            failedTestsCount = failed;
        });
        console.log("Failed tests: " + failedTestsCount)
        mocha.unloadFiles();
        await delay(1000*60) // 1 minute   
    }
```